# how can I show the different words between txt files?

Tags: java, textfield

My assignment is to compare two text files.

Everything is working alright except for the fact that once it reaches end of file, it crashes because theres no more lines to read.

I added an if statement to check if theres a next line, if there's not, get out of the loop, but im getting this error:

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
if(infile1.hasNext() && infile2.hasNext())
```

instead of

```
if(line1.hasNext() && line2.hasNext())
```

Comment: how can ı show the different words between these txt files instead of showing the lines?

Comment: You can create a new scanner for the lines (or just `split()` on spaces)

Comment: which line i should use? Or how can I use this method called "split()?   I think I should use  String class split() method to split that long text into an array of String (one array element per line)
but how can i do that??

Comment: can you give me an example to start with anything please I have confused :(

Comment: [`String[] words = line.split(" ")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

You have a `String line = infile.nextLine();`, which reads lines. You can also use [`infile.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29). By default this method uses whitespace to space for tokens, so this includes spaces.

Also watch out with the checks you use. Use `hasNext()` with `next()`, `hasNextLine()`  with `nextLine()` and `hasNext(delimiter)` with `next(delimiter)`.

Comment: thank you but I couldn't adapt this question also I have to do that with JTextArea. I want to do simple winmerge program but only show the differences and to be bold for different words